# Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _getStatus BuleCappServiceUseDynamicDllDlg.obj

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mfc, dllexport

I am created Regular DLLs Dynamically Linked to MFC...

in dll using export function

Example:
**extern "C" declspec(dllexport) bool getStatus()**

after build dll successfully.

then this **dll** and **lib** file import my new Project.
after **include all header file** to my new Project and this file to use build dll.

then i use export function in my project

in Build mode Successful after Use Release Mode
It get Linked Error  **LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _getStatus   BuleCappServiceUseDynamicDllDlg.obj**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set dependency in release mode also. 
     Rightclick on project->click on Property->c++->Additional Include Directories and write the name of dlls in both release and debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating implicitly linked library, exporting only. This will work for explicit linkage.

For implicit linking, you have to import symbols (functions) to your application.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397859/constructor-overloading-class-get-linker-error-using-dll); I think it may help you.